# How to implement hover vertical navigation submenu with Bootstrap way?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I required to build a vertical navigation with sub-menu / widget 's in that. How to create using Bootstrap 4.2.1 ?

here is the requirement:

[image: Vertical menu with sub menu / widget]

here is my try: 
Not works on mouse over, works only onclick. ( still the hover moved out sub menu shows )

html :

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#page-hero">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>MyIB
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#page-hero" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Store
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="menu-items " >

                    <div class="menu-point">
                        <div class="menu-wrapper collapse" id="submenu1">
                            <h3>Title goes here</h3>
                            <div class="nested-menu">
                                <div class="sub-menu" >
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">French</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">German</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Doutch</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sub-menu" >
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">French</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">German</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Doutch</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sub-menu" >
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">French</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">German</a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Doutch</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                </div>
            </li>
       </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below css code

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown>.dropdown-toggle:active {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

working fiddle link [here](https://codepen.io/bsngr/pen/frDqh).